# When typing arguments, do you use the type or the object?

Tags: python, dataframe, function, arguments, type-hinting

Say you want to specify the argument (`df`) of function to be a `pandas.Dataframe`.

```py
def fun(df: TYPE):
    # blabla that already exists but you did not
    # read pandas doc
```

Instead of `TYPE`, would you use `pandas.Dataframe` so the "object name", or `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` which is the return of `type(pandas.Dataframe)`?
And why?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: there's no real benefit in specifying the type right now.

Comment: I'd recommend trying `pandas.Dataframe` as the type (since it's shorter and simpler), then running `mypy` on your code to see if it complains.

Comment: I think `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` is a subclass of `pandas.Dataframe`. So it depends on how specific you need to be -- does it take any kind of dataframe, or just a core dataframe? Most likely the former.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh There is absolutely a benefit to specifying types in modern Python. The code itself runs the same, but IDE tools and extensions can now use explicit typing for recommendations, testing, improvements, better intellisense, etc.

Comment: @Barmar as you suggested: the former. Thank you for that precision.

Comment: @h0r53 agreed that

Comment: In that case you should use `pandas.Dataframe` as the type -- don't be more specific than necessary.